# Force PHP CLI to write files as www-data

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, permissions

Is there a way to make PHP CLI-invoked scripts to fwrite() as www-data?

Currently, if I create a text file and write to it using my own custom script `php writeToLogFile.php`, the file is created as root, and with very minimal permissions: rw- r-- r--

This means then if I want to write further data to this file in apache (running as www-data), I get permission denied.

This is part of a larger system, so it wouldn't be practical for me to chmod() or chown() each file I create. I also don't want to set the umask() in PHP as this may interfere with other threads.

I should also mention the file is being written to an NFS share on a different server (all servers are Ubuntu). The folder is shared as: `/myfolder/logsfiles 01.02.03.04(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash)`

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use `sudo` to run the script as `www-data`.

Comment: Is there anything in cli/php.ini that can globally change this, rather than specify at execution time?

Comment: Only a privileged process can change its userid. PHP doesn't have any special privileges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`php` can't change the userid that the process runs as, only privileged (e.g. setuid) programs can do this. You need to run the script as `www-data`.

```
sudo -u www-data php writeToLogFile.php
```

Comment: Thank you - this works, and I'll accept this as the answer, since it doesn't sound like PHP is privileged enough to change the userid that it runs as, as described by Barmar.

Answer (score 1):

execute `sudo su www-data && php writeToLogFile.php` this will first switch user and than execute your code as `www-data` user only...

Comment: Thank you for the response - I'm sure that would work, but I was hoping for a more system-wide solution, rather than focusing on an individual script execution

Comment: This won't work. The `php` command will be run in the original shell after you exit from the `su` shell, not in the shell executed by `su`.